# How to prevent windows text scaling current document

Tags: html, css, sass

is there a way to prevent Windows text scaling on a webpage and show not scaled web page even if windows font is scaled to 125% or 150%.

[image]

Comment: Do you have evidences that setting `font-size: 14px` the size gets changed too?

Comment: I need prevent scaling whole document, not only text

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the only units that will not scale when the screen zoom level is increased are the viewport percentage units (`vh` and `vw` and those based on these). These can be set as any other units:

```
p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

The following is from [MDNs explanation on these units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths):

> **vh**: Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.
>
> **vw**: Equal to 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block.
>
> **vmin**: Equal to the smaller of vw and vh.
>
> **vmax**: Equal to the larger of vw and vh.

To see how you can use these for text, there is an article over at [CSS-Tricks on Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). It might not be the right for every website, but it certainly is possible for the right use cases.